# creating a 3d kernel smooth surface and "slicing" it

Tags: r, 3d

as an example, consider the following data that creates a 3d graph (my actual data set is around 800 cases):

```
x <- runif(100)
y <- runif(100)
z <- sin(5*x)*cos(5*y)/5 + rnorm(100,0,0.1)
```

let's assume all i have are the actual x,y,z points (as a data set).
i would like to create (or fit?) a 3d smooth topographic surface graph and then "slice" the fitted surface into 2d slices so i can work on them separately (fitting regressions and what not).

{as a side note : not sure if rgl.surface() does kernel smoothing but when i try using it i get this error:
   Error in rgl.surface(x, y, z) : y length != x rows * z cols

the pdf for the rgl package shows a graph like this:
http://rgl.neoscientists.org/arc/doc/RGL_INTERFACE03.pdf
(page 8)}

can anyone recommend a type of kernel smoother and a "slicing" technique? I've looked into ksmooth but i know that are a lot more out there.

Comment: There are a couple of 2d kernel density estimators in pkgs: MASS and KernSmooth. You should provide a more detail specification of how you expect "slicing" to be represented.

Comment: thank you for the replay! once that fitted surface has been created, i would like to slice to n slices along the y axis. that way, i get 2d graphs describing the z~x relationship at a given y value.

Comment: I was off-base on those leads. They are for density estimation, nor multidimensional smoothing. Let me change my suggestion to using this `library(sos); findFn(' multidimensional smoothing')`

Comment: The offered example needs some sort of spline fitting procedure before it would be ready to pass to rgl. The surface3d function requires its third argument to be an n x m matrix and your z variable only has a single value at each of the (x,y) pairs.